# Is Camel Shiro thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, apache-camel, shiro

It appears when doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) in the org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm is called the UsernamePasswordToken passed is that of another user.

The trace below explains what I am getting at:

fetching List user1 
fetching List user1-role 
roles for user user1 is/are user1-role..
permissions for user user1 is/are iswapi:service1:, iswapi:service2:..

Those are print outs from the custom implementation of the AuthorizingRealm.
Basically, I get the principals:

String user = (String) getAvailablePrincipal(principals);

and I fetch the roles for that user (which prints out the >>> fetching List ..... line). Surprisingly, the user being printed is user1, when in reality the user that made the call is user2.

The question is, why is getAvailablePrincipal(principals) returning user1 instead of user2? Is that the right call to make to know the current owner/user of that context? I believe getAvailablePrincipal(principals) should return the user in the SHIRO_SECURITY_TOKEN header, but this is not happening.

After a few research/debugging, I realize Shiro gets the current thread's user by doing

Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

However, the problem is in camel OSGi, the thread is always re-used therefore the new request coming in a re-used thread will always have the user of the first thread.

This I found out printing out the thread runing the Realm which I found out has a thread id and thread name of user1. Hence, user1's roles will always be fetched for user2.

If my assumptions are correct, how do I go about ensuring a new thread for a new request?

Note:
My camel bundle uses direct:vm component which I think uses the thread of the source/originating endpoint. When I printed out the thread id & name it looks like:

Thread ID: 5944
Thread Name: qtp406786712-5944
Thread Group Name: spring-osgi-extender[1db479f4]-threads
Thread Group Parent Name: org.springframework.osgi.extender-1.2.1